# ehcach and spring @cachable - how to cach no matter input values

Tags: spring, annotations, ehcache

I have method with one input which I use for logging purposes only.
How can I use `@Cacheable` on this method while ignoring the input?
(using Ehcache and spring `@Cacheable` annotation)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the `@Cacheable` annotation with the `key` attribute and give it a constant value, thus ignoring your input parameter.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key) for details.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it.